# Woocommerce Product List Thumbnail Link

Tags: php, wordpress, function, woocommerce

I want to display a lightbox of the full-size featured image when I click on the thumbnail in the admin products list. Is there  a hook that can override the default link? I would still need the product title to link to the product edit page.

Answer (score 0):

You can use the `post_thumbnail_html` filter to modify the HTML output of the thumbnail.

```
function override_product_thumbnail_link($html, $post_id, $post_thumbnail_id, $size, $attr) {
    // Get the product permalink
    $product_permalink = get_edit_post_link($post_id);

    // Get the full-size image URL
    $full_image_url = wp_get_attachment_url($post_thumbnail_id);

    // Modify the thumbnail HTML to include a lightbox link
    $html = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s" data-lightbox="product-image">%s</a>',
        esc_url($full_image_url),
        $html
    );

    // Wrap the thumbnail HTML with the product permalink
    $html = sprintf(
        '<a href="%s">%s</a>',
        esc_url($product_permalink),
        $html
    );

    return $html;
}
add_filter('post_thumbnail_html', 'override_product_thumbnail_link', 10, 5);
```

Comment: This isn't working for me. To be clear, I'm talking about the featured image thumbnail in the admin products list.